# Canvas to PhotoLibrary [Phonegap]

Tags: canvas, cordova

Well, I have dealed quite well with several images onto canvas and now the questions lays in exporting to Photo library on iOS throught Phonegap. I've read a lot relates to the Phonegap API, and lot of tests as well, but no results.

Is there any plugin for Phongap which allows to access the photo library in IOS? I saw one for Android :(.

If not (I found canvas2image.js) which are your experiences about this topic?

Every info will be apreciated.

Thanks in avance,
DGM.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read this and thought "how hard could it be?".

So I hacked one up real quick.

Let me know if it works OK.

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

#### Example

In your html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="165px" height="145px"></canvas>
```

then in `onDeviceReady`:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    var canvas2ImagePlugin = window.plugins.canvas2ImagePlugin;
}
```

then in the function to save your canvas:

```
// where myCanvasId == 'myCanvas' (the id of the canvas above)
function mySavingFunction(myCanvasId) {
    canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }, 
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }, 
        myCanvasId
    );
}
```

Comment: Next week I'll give you feedback (I swear it!). Thank very much.

Comment: I tried with this plugin but am getting uncaught referenceerror : saveImageDataToLibrary is not defined at file index.html... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

After few years, the plugin can do more and support IOS previous issued.

Now u can choose either to `save as jpg/png`, `set quality` and `set outputfolder`

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);  //msg is the filename path (for android and iOS)
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        '.jpg', // save as jpg
        80, // image quality
        'cunvaspluginfolder' //folder name
    );
}
```

Credit to [wbt11a](https://github.com/wbt11a) because make this plugin more configurable from original author.

Please download the new plugin here [Github source](https://github.com/wbt11a/Canvas2ImagePlugin)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solutions consists in re-write the khamer's plugin SaveImage from: https://github.com/khamer/phonegap-plugins-official/tree/master/iPhone/SaveImage

Greetings,
DGM.-