# save image with text as a image to photo gallery in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a temporary image which i want to copy to gallery using javascript(phonegap).
Any help?

```
function save() {
  var image = document.getElementById("tempImg");
  //upload image to gallery of mobile . But how??
}
```

My image contains photo and text together...

i just want to arrange all div data including image inside div with some text on it and save it as an full image with any format .jpg,png etc in javascript.
I referred this link but that is for canvas to image but i want div to image .
[Canvas to PhotoLibrary [Phonegap]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912936/canvas-to-photolibrary-phonegap)

Comment: can you show an example (e.g. screenshot) of what your "image" looks like?

Comment: @VladStirbu : It shouldn't matter what the image looks like. I imagine that it is dynamically created/edited by the user. At any rate, I was able to [answer the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15914207/2093695) without knowing what it looks like.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out this url: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/.

Using this script, you can convert your div into a canvas, then use the "Canvas to PhotoLibrary [Phonegap]" to do the rest.

Your code would look something like this:

```
function save() {
    var image = document.getElementById("tempImg");
    html2canvas(image, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // use "Canvas to PhotoLibrary [Phonegap]" on the canvas variable
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you save this using session storage(or)local storage

save:

```
var z1,z2,z3;
function save() {
var a=$("#theme1_text").val();
var b=$("#image_div").css("background-image");              
var c=$("#background_theme1").css("background-image");
sessionStorage.z1=a;
sessionStorage.z2=b;
sessionStorage.z3=c;
    };
```

view:

```
function view() {
$("#theme1_text").val(sessionStorage.z1);
$("#image_div").css("background-image",sessionStorage.z2);
$("#background_theme1").css("background-image",sessionStorage.z3);
    };
```

Comment: This won't actually save it to the PhotoLibrary or even convert it into an image, will it?