# Save png or jpg file from canvas in ios using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to copy an image file from canvas and save it to photos in iphone using phonegap. I use the js file 
    https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin/tree/master/www

```
 <div class="win-n-lose-wrapper" id="workbox">
   <div class="left-img"><img id="winner" src="img/img-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="right-img"><img id="looser" src="img/img-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <canvas id="mycanvas" style="display:block;"></canvas>
 </div>   
 <div class="next-wrapper">
   <a class="btn_back" title="back" onclick="goBack();">Back</a>
   <a class="btn" title="Next" onclick="share();">Copy</a>
 </div>

</body>
```

and here is the code rest

```
function share()
{

   var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

   $('.save').attr({
                'download': 'image.png',  /// set filename
                'href'    : image              /// set data-uri
                });
}
```

I have not done any settings for this.

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: image is not saved in photos

Comment: check my answer here [save canvas to photogallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912936/canvas-to-photolibrary-phonegap/33052876#33052876)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good phonegap plugin for that.

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Hope this helps

Comment: yes i follow this one but not able to solved. May be somwhere i missed with some settings

Comment: check if the plugin is being added to cordova_plugins.js and config.xml. if not than try rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

For Saving image you can use:

```
function saveImage()
{
    var canvas2ImagePlugin = window.plugins.canvas2ImagePlugin;
    canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(function(msg){console.log(msg);},function(err){console.log(err);},'yourCanvasId');
}
```

Comment: no not really done. will i need to add anything else?

Comment: @swatisrivastav: You need to include the js file ` <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="YourPath/Canvas2Image/Canvas2ImagePlugin.js"></script>`

Comment: path what? as i have this Canvas2ImagePlugin.js within www folder

Comment: @swatisrivastav: How will you include a js file to your html file ? Include the above mentioned file like that. Replace that `yourpath`, it's a place holder