# Canvas2Image Plugin for Cordova not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I am trying to save the contents of a canvas in a PhoneGap app on Android.  I am using the Canvas2ImagePlugin, found at: 
https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

For the life of me, I cannot get it to work.  I have tried to install and re-install multiple times with no success.

```
function clickSave() {
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            alert(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );
}
```

When trying to run the function I don't even get the alert saying that it worked or failed.  It really should be a very simple function!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but it works for me, add a script **AFTER** including the `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` in your HTML file, then add an event listener in the script you've just created

`

```
<script>
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                     alert("Got deviceready");
                    var canvas2ImagePlugin = window.plugins.canvas2ImagePlugin;
            }
          // where myCanvasId == 'myCanvas' (the id of the canvas above)
                function mySavingFunction(myCanvasId) {
                    canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
                        function(msg){
                           alert(msg);
                            alert("Saving image is successful!");
                        }, 
                        function(err){
                            alert(err);
                        }, 
                        myCanvasId
                    );
                }
```

`
and in your HTML file, do this

`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="165px" height="145px"></canvas>
  <button onclick="mySavingFunction(myCanvas)">Save my canvas!</button>`

It won't work if you will test it in a browser, build your project first then install it in your device or in a device emulator to make it work.

This is where i got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912936/canvas-to-photolibrary-phonegap). Hope this solves your problem.