# Ionic App - Canvas2ImagePlugin can't make it work using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I found this plugin that will enable me to save images in my App (I am having a hard time finding a solution in these particular subject). My question is how do I implement this in an angular way? I'm still new to angular.js that is why i',m still confused as hell. Anyway, it says

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    ); 
}
```

and the onDeviceReady in angular ionic app is in this part right?

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) { 
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }  
// THIS IS WHERE I CAN PUT THE ABOVE CODE AM I RIGHT?
  });
})
```

I have done this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }  
      window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );
  });
})
```

Where i inserted the code that will enable me to use the plugin. But I'm getting an error in my console:

[image]

Any tip, or help will be appreciated, again I'm still very new to angular.js sorry for the noob question.

Comment: could you please add `script` loading sequence part of your `index.html`

Comment: I forgot to link the plugin, here it is: https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Comment: <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin/www/Canvas2ImagePlugin.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution based from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912936/canvas-to-photolibrary-phonegap), I added an event listener in a seperated script AFTER calling the   `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` in my html file.

JS

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
             alert("Got deviceready");
            var canvas2ImagePlugin = window.plugins.canvas2ImagePlugin;
    }


  // where myCanvasId == 'myCanvas' (the id of the canvas above)
        function mySavingFunction(myCanvasId) {
            canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
                function(msg){
                   alert(msg);// the filename and path where the image is saved
                }, 
                function(err){
                    alert(err);
                }, 
                myCanvasId
            );
        }
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="165px" height="145px"></canvas>
<button onclick="mySavingFunction(myCanvas)">Save Canvas</button>
```

It won't work if you will test it in the browser, I don't know why, but it only works when you build your ionic project `ionic build android` and installing it in a device or in a device emulator (Genymotion or Bluestacks).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you had wrong script sequence, you should load `app.js` file after all angular files & `Canvas2ImagePlugin` javascript code gets loaded.

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script> <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/org.devgeeks.Canvas2ImagePlugin/www/Canvas2ImagePlugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: the 2nd error in log is gone, but the 3rd is still present. I'm thinking if I can wrap it in a function inside the deviceready like this?

`function saveImage() {
        window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(err);
            },
            document.getElementById('myCanvas')
        );
    }`

Comment: then use the saveImage and connect it in a button? i tried but there is no log that says it is successful or what based on this `console.log(msg);`

Comment: @JedNocum I think you should call that function on device ready as suggested here https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Comment: Correction, the 3rd is gone but the 2nd error log is still present, im sorry. `Canvas2ImagePlugin.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Comment: Can you provide me a way how to do this? where should i insert the code and how to initialize it?